# What resources do I get with the Free tier of Google Kubernetes Engine with an Autopilot Cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The [Google Kubernetes Pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) says that I would be charged a $0.10 Management fee for my autopilot clusters, but [this](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#kubernetes-engine) page says that this cost is not applied to my first cluster. Plus, I get monthly $74.4 free credit for usage on GKE. So, if I use only one cluster, what amount of resources (vCPUs, RAM, Storage) do I get for free?

Also, please tell if I missed/misunderstood some documentation regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GKE free tier (which is actually a monthly credit of $74.40) covers the management fee ($0.10 per hour) for one GKE Autopilot or Zonal cluster per billing account.  The credit only covers the management fee, so you will be charged for the resources used by workloads you deploy to your Autopilot cluster.  Google Cloud has other monthly credits which can be applied to the compute resources used by your Autopilot workloads.

Comment: So does that mean that the free tier is actually not free?

Comment: Depends on how you look at it.  The management fee is free, but you pay for your workloads.

Comment: You do get $300 GCP credit though when you sign up.

Comment: But still, it's just for the first 3 months, but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

Although Google spreads a bit the information, it is possible to get a fully free solution, even after the 90 days of $300 free credits.

*Disclaimer*: I am currently in my 90 days free credits and I will update as I complete the period

The current source of information is [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits). Here is a summary:

- You can get forever 1 GKE cluster for free:

  - either autopilot (they will assign a [e2-medium](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#e2-shared-core) machine (Medium machine type with 1 vCPU and 4 GB of memory, backed by a shared physical core.) in a single zone which it seems you can choose. However they mention other places that Compute Engine free tiers is only in us-west1, us-east1, us-central1 so I would select one of these
  - or Zonal (create a Standard cluster in a single zone). I am not 100% sure you can go with an e2-medium machine type as in the Compute Engine section, the free tiers only allow e2-micro (Micro machine type with 0.25 vCPU and 1 GB of memory, backed by a shared physical core.)
- then comes the cost of your pods and storage. If you use only the above cluster, you need to ensure that:

  - the sum of your pods resources stay under the machine type specifications (i.e. 25% of the month hour if e2-micro and 1GB of RAM, 100% of the month hours for e2-medium and 4GB of RAM - see image below for details)
    [image: CPU usage per machine type]
  - the sum of your storage usage is less than 5GB HDD per month
  - the sum of your network egree (outbound of the pods) is less than 1GB per month (excluding China and Australia)

The above *should* give you completely free cluster. However the amount of resources being very small, all you can do is test your deployment automation or run simple (most likely stateless) website/API

**Off-topic**: if you want to stick with Google Cloud and ok to pay some small amount per month, you can always use a bigger machine type that suits your needs. You're charged for what you use. You can put some automation to terminate the pods when unused. I will probably play with these soon.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't think that the e2-micro would be enough for my usage. I had to deploy a few discord bots and websites, and one of the discord bots had machine learning, which is a reason I want a server with good specs, plus as cheap as possible. Anyway, now I have chosen Contabo as a VPS (really cheap) and am using Platform9 free tier to manage my cluster.